Incorrectly recognized display monitor
I have attached two monitors, Samsung 24" and Westinghouse 40" using HDMI cable to GPU (Nvidia GTX 3060) and motherboard (Gigabyte Z790) respectively. However, the system (Jellyfish) does not recognize the second display, and calls it Unknown 36" display. I use both displays simultaneously using 'join the displays' configuration (Screenshot attached).

The second display gives a blurred output (document fonts are worst affected) that puts a strain on the viewers. Images and videos seem to be okay. The first display (24") is always fine.
Solutions tried:

I have tried different levels of fractional scaling, but no improvement is visible.
I also tried changing the resolution using xrandr. No luck.
Interchange the displays. 40" display does not work with the GPU.
Tried different HDMI ports (1 & 2) on GPU and the display monitor (1, 2 & 3).
Tried changing DPI, as suggested here; but not sure if I implemented correctly.

Appreciate any ideas.
Dan Mahadik
